# Getting {xml_nodeset (0)} even though CSS selector recognizes node

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the data from the table found [here,](https://craftednba.com/player-traits/length) specifically the name, length, height, and wingspan. With SelectorGadget, it says the names are contained in the `.text-left a` node, and says that there are 411 objects (which seems correct given the table contains 411 players).

Yet, when running the following code, I get an empty list.

```
library(rvest)
library(polite)
library(tidyverse)

crafted <- read_html("https://craftednba.com/player-traits/length")

names <- crafted %>% 
  html_nodes(".text-left a") %>% 
  html_text()
```

I found this other post where someone seems to have had a similar problem and the top answer says to not use SelectorGadget. Following their instructions, I still didn't get anything with the following code:

```
library(V8)

ctx <- v8()

crafted <- read_html("https://craftednba.com/player-traits/length")

html_node(crafted, xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "text-left", " " ))]//a')
  html_text() %>% 
  ctx$eval()

names <- ctx$get("text-left")
```

```
{xml_missing}
<NA>
 Error in xml_text(x, trim = trim) : 
argument "x" is missing, with no default
 Error: ReferenceError: text is not defined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you check the Developer Tools in your browser when you load the page you'll see that the HTML is loaded with the data obfuscated in a script tag. You have some options, either automate a browser to get the data or reverse engineer the script that puts the data in the right place

Comment: Thanks for the response @childnick. How can/should I go about either of those methods? Also, what’s the reason for obfuscating non-sensitive and public (albeit non-centralized) data?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to automate the browser to pull the table:

```
# load libraries
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

# define target url
crafted_url <- "https://craftednba.com/player-traits/length"


# start RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------------

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4550L, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

# Navigate to webpage -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$navigate(crafted_url)


# pull the webpage html
# then read it
page_html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
              read_html()


# search for <table> node on the page's html
tables <- page_html  %>%   html_table() 

# print the first (and only table)
tables[[1]]
```